# How to enforce the concrete class take a concrete instance as argument?

Tags: java, oop

Here is my use case,

```
public interface dataModel {
   //nothing
}
public interface dataRepo {
    public doIt(dataModel a);
}
public class concreteDataModel implements dataModel {
    public doIt(dataModel a);
}
public class concreteDataRepo implements dataRepo {
    public doIt(dataModel a);
}
```

I feel like i am doing this wrong.  I have several datarepo and datamodel. I want the repo takes the datamodel of its own kind. Is there any design pattern to make this clean?

Comment: What do you mean by `of its own kind` ? Give a concrete example of what is forbidden and allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generics.

```
public interface dataModel {
   //nothing
}
public interface dataRepo<T extends dataModel> {
    public doIt(T a);
}
public class concreteDataModel implements dataModel {
    public doIt(dataModel a);
}
public class concreteDataRepo implements dataRepo<concreteDataModel> {
    public doIt(concreteDataModel a);
}
```

Comment: Isn't it `public doIt(dataRepo<T> a)` ? He said `of its own kind`, that's why I ask.

Comment: @Dici which line are you referring to? My understanding was that he wants to tie a datamodel and data repo together on the datarepo implementation.  Maybe the OP can update his the question a bit.

Comment: The one you changed ! In dataRepo, but in fact I would like the OP to clarify its question, I'm not sure I understood it well so my comment might not be relevant

Answer (score 0):

You could try generics:

```
interface dataModel { }
class concreteDataModel implements dataModel { }

interface dataRepo<E extends dataModel> {
    public void doIt(E a);
}

class concreteDataRepo implements dataRepo<concreteDataModel> {

    @Override
    public void doIt(concreteDataModel a) {

    }
}
```